# Passing Angular component to another one

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I know this has been asked before but I don't understand those answer to be honest. I want to make something simple:

Basically I have this:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel__track">
     <li ngFor="let slideHtml of SlidesHTML?" class="carousel__slide">
       **THIS IS ACTUALLY WHERE I WANT TO PASS ANOTHER HTML COMPONENT**
       i.e: <app-slideHtml>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to achieve that basically, but I don't know if I can go with `@Input() html` or if I need to use `ng-content` for that. What do I need to put in the `.ts` file?

Edit: I'm using `ngFor` directive in the li element, so I can display actually all the slides. I don't know if that's even possible, I just wanted to see If I can actually achieve that.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. You want to display <app-order-product> for each <li> ?

Comment: Yes, I will display different components for each li, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can

```
<li *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="carousel__slide">
    <!-- Rename inputName by the actual input name you want-->
    <app-slideHtml [inputName]="slide.someData"></app-slideHtml>
</li>
```

Where `inputName` is the name of the `@Input` in *app-slideHtml* and `someData` an attribute of slide.

In `app-slideHtml.component.ts`

```
@Input() inputName: any; // Rename 'inputName' by the actual input name you want
```

You can pass the whole object instead of some attributes by passing `slide` to the input.

Comment: Yeah, something like that I was searching for. Thanks.